# Calculating distances in grid map (with obstacles)

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid

To simplify the use case to bare bones, I'm using an array like a grid map and calculating distances (steps) between different points in the grid. It should be as simple as summing the difference of the row and col numbers of two points. Like this:

```
const grid = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
];
const point1 = [0, 3];
const point2 = [3, 2];
const distance12 = Math.abs(point1[0] - point2[0]) + Math.abs(point1[1] - point2[1]) // = 4
```

However it gets tricky if you add "obstacles" in the grid. The array `grid` tells whether a cell can be used in the path. If it's 1 it can be used but if it's 0 then it's an obstacle. How do I calculate distances in this scenario with the obstacles?

```
const grid = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
];
const point1 = [0, 3];
const point2 = [3, 2];
const distance12 = ??? // = 8
```

I tried using a flood fill algorithm. It worked just fine without obstacles but broke down with more complex grid map.

Comment: try A* (a star). Your current example only works if values are 1. If the grid values are random values it does not work, in which case you should also use a*

Comment: @depperm The algorithm looks complicated and all existing libraries are for pathfinding, not calculating distance per se. Could the algorithm be tweaked to complete the function I'm after?

Comment: it is path finding (you have obstacles, you have start, you have end), find the shortest path and that is your distance, [this](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html) is a great reference (with pseudo code)